# Creating a layout within a View-extended class

Tags: android, uiview, view

I am still pretty new to Android development, and I have not been able to find any examples of how to do this.

In my Activity, I use "setContextView(new myViewClass)" to designate a View-extended class as the one to load.  Everything works fine in terms of loading the view, where I create various elements (LinearLayouts, buttons, etc.) based on a number of conditions.  Unfortunately, I cannot get any of these elements to actually appear on the screen.

I guess my question goes to a greater understanding of Views.  All of the examples I've seen concern setting an xml file as the base view and then altering it within the code.  Is there some alternative to this?

Thanks.

Here is an example code I've been trying to make work.  There are other things going on, but this is the relevant info.  For program context, this class is substantiated with the `setContextView(new createView(this))`:

```
public createView(Context c){
    super(c);

    // Create a simple layout
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(top.getContext());
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);


    // Create test text
    TextView mTestText = new TextView(c);
    mTestText.setText("This is a test");

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    layout.addView(mTestText, lp);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not adding the layout to your **CreateView**. However, the **View** class does not have an **add** method (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html).

Since **LinearLayout** is the base view for your extended view, you could extend **LinearLayout** instead and add the **TextView** to your extended class. If you do this, your **CreateView** class would probably look something like this:

```
/**
 * Since the LinearLayout is the base layout, we'll extend it.
 */
public class CreateView extends LinearLayout {
    public CreateView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        TextView mTestText = new TextView(context);
        mTestText.setText("This is a test");

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
        addView(mTestText, lp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But now that I have this layout, how do I make it appear on the screen?  My sense is that the view being created in my class is not being attached to the screen.  Do I need to return something, use an inflater, etc?

Comment: Either add the view to another view on the screen or set it as the content view. Use **setContentView** in your activity to set it as the main view. If you need a little example, I've zipped up my little test for the class in my answer: http://www.box.net/shared/j9x3076702